# Creating a swf from a set of images

Tags: flash, swfloader

I have a set of images, and I want to show them as a SWF slideshow. Something similar to Slideshare.net

It would be easiest if there is way I can pass a xml or json with list of images, and get the swf. I there a library or (linux friendly) tool, which I can use to do this? I am using Python with Django, but am open to using other languages etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a library called Ming that should be able to do this:

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php
and
http://www.libming.org/